# Duplicating elements by + 1 NOT x 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/zRDgK/

I'm working on building an experimental web design app, and came across a problem today. I'm trying to duplicate an element that I have selected (by adding/removing #stylethis id attr)

```
var MoveSelectedElement = function() {
    $('.drawing-area').children().drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
        dd.attrc = $( ev.target ).prop("className");
        dd.attrd = $( ev.target ).prop("id");
        dd.width = $( this ).width();
        dd.height = $( this ).height();
    })
    .drag(function( ev, dd ){
        var props = {};
        if ( dd.attrc.indexOf("E") > -1 ){
            props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width + dd.deltaX );
        }
        if ( dd.attrc.indexOf("S") > -1 ){
            props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height + dd.deltaY );
        }
        if ( dd.attrc.indexOf("W") > -1 ){
            props.width = Math.max( 32, dd.width - dd.deltaX );
            props.left = dd.originalX + dd.width - props.width;
        }
        if ( dd.attrc.indexOf("N") > -1 ){
            props.height = Math.max( 32, dd.height - dd.deltaY );
            props.top = dd.originalY + dd.height - props.height;
        }
        if ( dd.attrd.indexOf("stylethis") > -1 ){
            props.top = dd.offsetY;
            props.left = dd.offsetX;
        }
        $('#stylethis').css( props );
    }, {relative:true});

    $('.drawing-area *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
        if(moveable) {
            // Add stylethis class
            $('div.handle').remove();
            $('.drawing-area, .drawing-area *').removeAttr('id');
            $(this).attr('id', 'stylethis').append('<div class="handle NE"></div><div class="handle NN"></div><div class="handle NW"></div><div class="handle WW"></div><div class="handle EE"></div><div class="handle SW"></div><div class="handle SS"></div><div class="handle SE"></div>');
        }
    });
};
```

This is how I'm duplicating elements.

```
$(".duplicate").on('click touchend', function() {
    $('.drawing-area').append($("#stylethis").parent().html());
    $('.drawing-area, .drawing-area *').removeAttr('id');
    $('div.handle').remove();
    MoveSelectedElement();
});
```

The problem I have is after I duplicate the selected element a second time (after two have already been added) instead of adding 1 it adds the other two, and so on multiplying by 2. I only want to duplicate the selected element by 1 (hence the word "duplicate"). I'm not sure why it's acting the way it is.

If anyone can help assist me with this problem it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$('.drawing-area').append($("#stylethis").parent().html());
```

inside the code that duplicates the elements, use

```
$('.drawing-area').append($("#stylethis").clone());
```

Your code does actually duplicate the entire `.drawing-area` content, that holds **all** the *select* divs.

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zRDgK/1/